# Block incoming messages in iphone using swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to make iphone app to block all incoming messages when i want even if my iphone is connected with network, so i want to know is there any possibility to block incoming phone massages, and app messages like whatsapp, facebook? if yes, then what is the way?
please help me.

Comment: There's no any way! Because they're managed by the system.

Comment: Ask the user to turn on Do Not Disturb mode. There's no way to do that programatically

Comment: turn your phone off, that pretty much blocks every application to receive messages; however the phone won't be connected to network at that time and you can't use your phone either but life is about making compromises.

Comment: It would be nice if you would actually check the answer

Answer (score 1):

***Short Answer:*** NO, impossible.

---

***Long Answer:*** It is impossible to block incoming messages, because they enter the system in the form of **`Push Notifications`** from the apps that trigger them. You cannot block push notifications during your app's process, because the **`Notifications`**(in this case messages) do not belong to your app, but to the service that triggers them (Messages, Facebook etc.) and they are handled by the system.

---

The only thing left to do in this case is asking your users to activate ***Do not disturb*** or to shut down the phone, which isn't quite what you were looking for :-)